# avoid logging on jboss

Tags: logging, configuration, jboss, log4j

I m using jboss as application server. When I deploy my application on server it prints logs on jboss. So, can anybody tell how and where to create logging.properties file to manage the logs on jboss. please reply me as soon as possible.

thank you.

Comment: Should be tagged with jboss tag too.

Comment: JBoss doesn't use `logging.properties`, it uses Log4j. The only way to change JBoss's logging is to change its `conf/jboss-log4j.xml` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [JBoss Documentation about logging](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/latest/logging.html).

And an article about [JBoss logging configuration](http://java.dzone.com/articles/configuring-logging-jboss).

Good reading.

**Edit** :

You can set the JDK logging property :

```
java.util.logging.config.file = myLoggingFile.properties
```

You can also launch the JBoss Server with the good JAVA_OPTS (example for JDK1.4) :

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Dorg.jboss.logging.Logger.pluginClass=logging.JDK14LoggerPlugin 
           -Djava.util.logging.config.file=myLoggingFile.properties"
```

Comment: hi, Thank for reply but, I don't want to modify or change in jboss-log4j.xml. So, can u help me for creating my won logger configuration file(.properties file) which will take by jboss instead of jboss-log4j.xml